# Delete extensionless files which names end with '_C' string

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a batch code which cleans files which are older than 15 days. But I want to only delete files that end with '_C' and they have no extension.

Here is my code:

```
SET mypath=%cd%/downloads 

ForFiles /p %mypath% /d -15 /c "cmd /c For /R %%A in (*_C.*) Do (del /q @fname)
```

Here are my files:

> File Name: ---------Date:
>
> A_C_123_C ------                   18.02.2019
>
> A_C_456_C ------                    01.01.2018
>
> A_C_789_C  ------                   01.01.2018
>
> ***Testfile***-------------                01.01.2018
>
> tmp.txt -------------                      01.01.2018

When I execute the code, it cleans ***Testfile*** also. I just want to delete extensionless files that end with '_C' and older than 15 days.

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not require incorporating the `for` loop into the `forfiles` command. `forfiles` has it's own search switch `/s`

You specifically mention you want to only do files ending with `_C` with no extension, but you added `*_C.*` which in fact means anything before `_C` with a dot and anything after the dot. You really just need:

```
@forfiles /p %mypath% /d -15 /s /m *_C /c "cmd /c If @IsDir==FALSE del @path"
```